# How to import a module and bind it to a button in a tkinter window

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter, module

I can't `bind` a `Button` to a `module` in `tkinter` window( Actually it's not even showing a window)

I `import` the `module` but it run, **I want to run it after I click a button, not before**.

How can I do that, any help will be greatly appreciated. here's my code for GUI and the Module

```
from Tkinter import*
import Tkinter as Tk

from DatasetCreator1 import DatasetCreator
class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.TrainButton = Button(frame, text="Begin Train", 
                                  command = DatasetCreator.insertOrUpdate) 
        self.TrainButton.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side = LEFT)

root = Tk()
b = Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this it runs the `DatasetCreator1` directly, without showing any `tkinter` window. And it asks for input:

```
 enter your id
```

---

And my `DatasetCreator1` is:

```
import cv2
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier('Classifiers/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');


class DatasetCreator():
    def insertOrUpdate(Id,Name):
        conn=sqlite3.connect("Facebase0.db")
        cmd="SELECT * FROM People WHERE Id =" +str(Id)
        cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
        isRecordExist=0
        for row in cursor:
            isRecordExist=1
        if(isRecordExist==1):
            cmd="UPDATE people SET Name=' "+str(Name)+" ' WHERE ID="+str(Id)
        else:
            cmd="INSERT INTO people(ID,Name) Values("+str(Id)+",' "+str(Name)+" ' )"
        conn.execute(cmd)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    ID = raw_input("enter your id")
    name = raw_input("enter your name")
    insertOrUpdate(ID,name)
    sampleNum=0
    while(True):
        ret, img = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

            #incrementing sample number 
            sampleNum=sampleNum+1
            #saving the captured face in the dataset folder
            cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+ID +'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

            cv2.imshow('frame',img)
        #wait for 100 miliseconds 
        if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        # break if the sample number is morethan 20
        elif sampleNum>20:
            break
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And some interesting feature of my `DatasetCreator1` is, **it still runs `input('enter your id')`**
even if I delete the function call

```
 ID = raw_input("enter your id") # function call
 name = raw_input("enter your name")
 insertOrUpdate(ID,name)
 sampleNum=0
```

Or I give no parameter at function definition

```
class DatasetCreator():
    def insertOrUpdate(Id,Name): # function definition
        conn=sqlite3.connect("Facebase0.db")
        cmd="SELECT * FROM People WHERE Id =" +str(Id)
        cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
```

Comment: You have **indentation** error, starting at line `ID = raw_input(...`

Comment: `import` always run code which is not in functions or classes - so put code in functions or classes to control it. Or put in `if __name__ == "__main__": ` to run it only when you start it directly, but not when you import it.

Comment: I solved it. It had lot's of errors.